# where did i go wrong when setting up ssl?

Tags: windows, iis, ssl, iis-6

I needed my site to be able to do https, however after I set it up on my server https://www.mysite.com/ 
says it is secure, but no page can be found. It shows the little green lock and everything.

While http://www.mysite.com/ displays the page and everything works fine.

note: I set up the certificate for iis 6 windows server 2003

What did I mess up while doing the set up that would cause https not to be found?

Comment: Post your bindings from IIS that show your IP address, etc...  You may have set that incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have posted error message that we can give exact answer of this query. I am sure there is some issue in setting up SSL on IIS 6. You can refer Microsoft official guide on how to install SSL on IIS 6 here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299875

or contact your SSL certificate provider; I am sure they can support you to solve this issue.